I can't upload an image to google form with selenium
I’m encountering a problem while automating the upload of a file (a photo) in a Google Form using Selenium and undetected_chromedriver. My goal is to fill out the Google Form and upload an image via a "file" input field. However, I’m facing a major challenge: the form contains an iframe, and the iframe’s ID changes on each load, making it difficult to interact with elements inside the iframe.
Problem
When I try to interact with the elements inside the iframe to upload the file, I’ve noticed that the iframe’s ID changes dynamically, which prevents Selenium from reliably locating the element on each run. My goal is to successfully navigate inside this iframe and upload the photo, but I’m struggling to handle the dynamic iframe IDs.
What I’ve Tried
Locating the iframe using XPath: I’ve used WebDriverWait to wait for the iframe to be present before selecting it. However, since the iframe’s ID changes on each run, this isn’t reliable.

Switching to the iframe using CSS Selectors: I also tried locating the iframe using a generic CSS selector (like iframe), but this fails when the page structure changes.

Sending the file path via send_keys(): Once I manage to navigate to the iframe, I try to click on the “Browse” button, but sometimes the element isn’t interactive yet, causing errors.

My Goal
I’m looking for a solution that will allow me to:
Reliably locate and interact with the iframe, despite the dynamic change of its ID.
Click the "Browse" button (or equivalent) inside the iframe.
Upload a photo using the "file" input field.
Submit the form after uploading the file.

Specific Questions
How can I handle the dynamic change of the iframe’s ID? Is there a more robust way to select the iframe even when its ID keeps changing (for example, using another attribute like class or name)?

What are the best ways to ensure the "Browse" element is clickable? I’d like to know if there are reliable approaches for interacting with elements inside a dynamic iframe by waiting for them to become truly interactive.

Do you have suggestions for avoiding errors related to timing issues? How can I improve the management of wait times and avoid synchronization problems between interacting with the page and the iframe?

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions regarding this issue. If you’ve encountered similar situations or have tips on managing dynamic iframes in Selenium, I’d love to hear your insights.
Thank you so much for your time and expertise!
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
import time

# Configuration des options de Chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = r"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1"
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={profile}")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True)

# Chemin du fichier à uploader
file_path = os.path.abspath("./01.png")  # Remplacez par le chemin réel de votre fichier

try:
    # Étape 1 : Ouvrir le formulaire
    print("Étape 1 : Ouvrir le formulaire")
    try:
        driver.get("https://forms.gle/HcKLXz9ErXkm63qK8")
        print("Formulaire ouvert avec succès.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur à l'étape 1 : {e}")
        driver.quit()
        exit()

    # Étape 2 : Cliquer sur le bouton "Add File" pour ouvrir le popup
    print("Étape 2 : Cliquer sur le bouton 'Add File'")
    try:
        add_file_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span/span[2]"))
        )
        add_file_button.click()
        print("Bouton 'Add File' cliqué avec succès.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur à l'étape 2 : {e}")
        driver.quit()
        exit()

    # Étape 3 : Localiser et basculer vers l'iframe
    print("Étape 3 : Localiser et passer à l'iframe")
    try:
        iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe"))
        )
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
        print("Passé à l'iframe avec succès.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur à l'étape 3 : {e}")
        driver.quit()
        exit()

    # Étape 4 : Cliquer sur le bouton "Browse" dans l'iframe
    print("Étape 4 : Cliquer sur le bouton 'Browse'")
    try:
        browse_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button"))
        )
        browse_button.click()
        print("Bouton 'Browse' cliqué avec succès.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur à l'étape 4 : {e}")
        driver.quit()
        exit()

    # Étape 5 : Trouver le champ input et envoyer le chemin du fichier
    print("Étape 5 : Envoyer le chemin du fichier au champ de téléchargement")
    try:
        file_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']"))
        )
        file_input.send_keys(file_path)
        print("Fichier téléchargé avec succès.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur à l'étape 5 : {e}")
        driver.quit()
        exit()

    # Étape 6 : Revenir au contexte principal et soumettre le formulaire
    print("Étape 6 : Soumettre le formulaire")
    try:
        driver.switch_to.default_content()  # Revenir au contexte principal
        submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/span"))
        )
        submit_button.click()
        print("Formulaire soumis avec succès.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur à l'étape 6 : {e}")
        driver.quit()
        exit()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Erreur générale : {e}")

finally:
    time.sleep(5)  # Attendre avant de fermer
    driver.quit()


I want to upload image to Google Form


path based locator should be fine... or just get all //iframe and iterate. If there are multiple, then switch to each one and check for the correct input element.  2) You shouldn't need to interact with the browse button, but if you have to click that for input to show up, use expected condition of elementToBeClickable.  You send keys to the <input type="file" element.  3)  Use the expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt


Locating the iframe using XPath: I’ve used WebDriverWait to wait for the iframe to be present before selecting it. However, since the iframe’s ID changes on each run, this isn’t reliable.
Assuming its the second iframe you are looking for
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'picker-dialog-content')]/descendant::iframe")

Switching to the iframe using CSS Selectors: I also tried locating the iframe using a generic CSS selector (like iframe), but this fails when the page structure changes.
use code above to get the current id of the iframe and just do i driver.switchTo().iframe
Sending the file path via send_keys(): Once I manage to navigate to the iframe, I try to click on the “Browse” button, but sometimes the element isn’t interactive yet, causing errors.
Just wait till button is clickable
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("buttonID")));
you might need to try a few different things to get this to work but once you have fixed switching to iframe the rest should be simple. Hope this helps
